# Remove or reduce INFO Violations on Sonar Qube 5.3 on a particular project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I want to either completely remove or reduce the count for INFO Violations (not other violations) on a particular project only. What is the best way to achieve this in Sonar Qube 5.3?

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few choices:

- Bulk update existing Info issues to mark them Won't Fix. (This doesn't keep more from being added in the next analysis)
- Create a Quality Profile which contains no Info issues and apply it to your project
- Configure your project with Issue exclusions for the info-level rules